# Direct print the document to server

Tags: c#

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Error: cannot find the default printer.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Exception: Error: cannot find the default printer.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[Exception: Error: cannot find the default printer.]
   Vriddhi.Registration.Print() in D:\Jitendra\My Works\Vriddhi2\Code\Vriddhi\Registration.aspx.cs:1018
   Vriddhi.Registration.PrintButtonClick(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Jitendra\My Works\Vriddhi2\Code\Vriddhi\Registration.aspx.cs:1000
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +118
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +112
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5563


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1
```

Comment: Looks like it can't find the default printer... If we had more info about what you are trying to do, and some code snippets in and around the offending areas, we might be able to help more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your webapp will run under a user account, that most likely hasn't defined a default printer. Most likely, it won't even have access privileges to any printer in the system.

You will need to fiddle with the account the app runs under and the printing privileges.

Comment: Thanks for Replay.. How to set account the app runs under and the printing privileges

Comment: For the privileges of the printer, just got to printer-properties and check, if your webapp user or one of his groups has printing privilege. I don't know how to set standard printer short of logging on interactivly as that user. You could enumerate the printers and chose one.